# Group rows by time interval

Tags: mysql, sql, gps

i have a database with very much rows from a gps sender. The gps have 1 seconds delay to send next row to the database. So what i want to do is a web interface that shows travels, i dont want to show much rows, i want to group the rows to trips. So i want to do is a query who can declare a trip/travel by checking if its more then 14 minutes to next row, if it is then make a row of all rows before a give it a trip number, else add it to the "travel" collection.

Comment: can you load a sqlfiddle.com with sample data - like a dozen rows, representing a 3-4 trips? The sample table only needs to have the logid and datetime fields.

Comment: now you can see it in the quastion @AgRizzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (example is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0c86/39)

```
SELECT Trip, MIN(Date_Time), MAX(Date_Time)
FROM (
  SELECT  @Trip := IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @Date_Time, Date_Time) <= 20, @Trip, @Trip+1) AS TRIP
    , logid
    , @Date_Time := Date_time AS Date_Time
  FROM gpslog
  JOIN (SELECT @TRIP := 1, @Date_Time := null ) AS tmp
  ORDER BY Date_Time) AS triplist
GROUP BY Trip
```

Comment: @AgRizzo, awesome solution. I was struggling with a similar problem here and your query worked for me perfectly. But, could you explain how it exactly works, please?

Comment: Let it go. I've run each subquery alone and I got it how it works. Anyway, maybe you can add a detailed explanation for people who reach your answer in future.

Comment: Can explain? I also need to know how this works @GustavoStraube thanks! Why `20` minutes? Instead of `more than 14 minutes`?